# What doing this style properties: *width: 363px !important; _width: 363px !important;

Tags: css, width

I found this code on one html email and can't understand what doing this prefixes. Are they important or they used for some email clients only?

`*width: 363px !important;`
`_width: 363px !important;`

Comment: [Those are hacks for older versions of Internet Explorer](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters--net-10575)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The properties with

the prefix * is to target IE 7 browser and below

the prefix _ is to target IE 6 browser.

Dont' use hacks. Use Conditional css to target different IE versions of browsers